# Create one file per week

Tags: java

I have a java program which is gonna be manually run every day.
Now I want to create an excel file per wek to write in it all tasks of the week

I know how to create a file every day like this:

```
if(!IoUtils.fileExist("indicators-" + IoUtils.getCurrentDate() + ".xls")){
    IoUtils.createIndicFile("indicators-" + IoUtils.getCurrentDate() + ".xls");
}
else IoUtils.INDIC_FILEPATH = "indicators-" + IoUtils.getCurrentDate() + ".xls";
```

Here is the function which give me the current date in a specific format:

```
// IoUtils class
public static String getCurrentDate(){
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).format(ldt);
}
```

So how can I change this to only create a file per week ?

I would also like to have the month and the number of the week in the filename like this:

```
// first monday of january 2018
name = "indicators-week1-01-2018"

// second monday of january 2018
name = "indicators-week2-01-2018"
```

Thank you

Comment: by writing it that way ... just check whether the system day is a monday before writing the file

Comment: What is your problem ? To check if the current day is the Monday ? Or to schedule the creation ?

Comment: @Stultuske please check the update

Comment: @vincrichaud I have updated the question

Comment: @AmadouBeye thx for the update. But still not clear where is your problem

Comment: @vincrichaud new update ! Sorry for my bad english ! I'm using google translate

Comment: @AmadouBeye No problem from the bad English ;-). The problem is that you show tyhe code that create the file. You show the code the get the date. But where is the code that make it happen every day ?

Answer (score 1):

Java provides ***java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor*** that can additionally schedule commands to run after a given delay, or to execute periodically.

```
Scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, StartDelay, repeatInterval, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Please note that if this will be running on multiple instances, a report will be generated for every instance separately.

Comment: @SofoGial In the `Runnable` run by the scheduled executor service, it is the job of the programmer to check for the correct date and to check if the file has been written yet for that week. So the executor repeating is a feature, not a problem.

Comment: @BasilBourque Absolutely! I have just pointed this out, since I have seen people forgetting this quite often in the last 5 years :)

Answer (score 1):

## Executor

Old-school way used the `Timer` class.

New-school way uses the [Executors framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) that handle the nitty-gritty details of scheduling tasks on background threads.

Set up an executor to run a `Runnable` every few hours. That task checks the current moment. If the day-of-week of the current date is a Monday, and if your file is not yet written, write it. If not, then let the Runnable expire. The [scheduled executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) will run again in a few hours, and repeat again and again.

The first step is to get the current date.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

from that get the current day of the week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = today.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

If today is a Monday, then see if file has yet been written. If not, write it.

```
if( dow.equals( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) {
    if( file not written ) { write file }
}
```

Put that all together into a named method.

```
private void writeFileOnMonday ( ) {
    ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
    DayOfWeek dow = today.getDayOfWeek();
    if ( dow.equals( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) {
        if ( file not written ){ write file }
    }
}
```

Harness that workload in a [scheduled executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Specify how many hours to wait between runs. If we specify to run our task every 3 hours, then, logic dictates, our weekly file will be written sometime between midnight and 3 AM on each Monday.

One big catch with a scheduled executor service: The repeating task execution comes silently to a halt if on any run a [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) ([`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) or [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)) is thrown by your task, and reaches the executor. So always wrap your task in a try-catch. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6894595/642706).

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();  // Convenience method to produce an executor service.

ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture =          // A handle to check the status of your task. May or may not be useful to you.
        scheduledExecutorService
                .scheduleWithFixedDelay( new Runnable() {  // Implement the `Runnable` interface as your task. 
                                             @Override
                                             public void run ( ) {
                                                 try {
                                                     writeFileOnMonday();
                                                 } catch (Exception e ) {
                                                     … handle unexected exception
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         } ,
                        0 ,                 // Initial delay
                        3 ,                 // Delay between runs.
                        TimeUnit.HOURS );   // Unit of time meant for the pair of delay numbers above.
```

Search Stack Overflow for more info, as all this has been covered many many times already.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create a quartz cron job scheduler `0 0 12 ? * MON`.
This will schedule job on every Monday at 12.00 PM.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `LocalDateTime`, you can do a check using `getDayOfWeek` method.

A example such as

```
if(LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY){
  // File Creation Logic ...
}
```

Comment: While this code works, the `ZonedDateTime` class is more appropriate that `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Agreed. Just working with what the question started with. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

use calender API, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) will return int 2 for Monday.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 2)
  if(!IoUtils.fileExist("indicators-" + IoUtils.getCurrentDate() + ".xls")){
      IoUtils.createIndicFile("indicators-" + IoUtils.getCurrentDate() + ".xls");
  }
  else IoUtils.INDIC_FILEPATH = "indicators-" + IoUtils.getCurrentDate() + ".xls";
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

String expectedFileName = "indicators-week"+week+"-whateveryouwant-"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Then you can check and if the file exists , write to the same file, if file does not exist you will create a new file with the expect file name and write to that new file.but based on the requirement year break should be handled properly

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).