# Why doesn't my Thread create a new one when it catches an Exception?

Tags: java

So I have a thread running like this:

```java
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("redo groupMonitor ... ");
                            if (redogmSafer < 1) {
                                groupMonitor.run(remoteHost, port);
                            } else {
                            }
                            redogmSafer = 100;
                        }
                    };
ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, delayStart, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

if (redogmSafer < 1) {
} else {
    service.shutdown();
    service.shutdownNow();
    redogmSafer = 0;
}
```

And I want to `run()` the `Thread` again, after it has exited due to an exception or else(Happens all 4-5 Hours).

I have tried to `shutdown()` and `shutdownNow()`, but that doesn't help either. It's like Java doesn't want to redo Threads once it has started been started and shutdown ...

Comment: That's correct. Once the thread terminated you can't start it again. But what is the problem since you use `scheduleAtFixedRate`? The task to execute get's executed again  later on. Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps you should explain `groupMonitor.run(remoteHost, port)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Thread like this:

```
Thread newThread = new Thread(runnable);

newThread.start();
```

or use an ExecutorService:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
executorService.execute(runnable);
```

But you are already using a ScheduledExecutorService which should do the job.

Comment: The Executors framework was invented to replace manually handling of threads.

Answer (score 0):

## Wrap your `Runnable` / `Callable` code with try-catch

A `ScheduledExecutorService` halts further scheduling upon receiving a `Throwable` (an `Exception` or `Error`). This halting is silent, with no error reported, and no messages or logging.

So you should be looking at prevention of the problem rather than a fix. The prevention is to wrap your `Runnable` / `Callable` code with a try-catch.

As long as no `Throwable` bubbling up the call stack reaches the scheduled executor service, the scheduling continues.

```java
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try{
                                System.out.println("redo groupMonitor ... ");
                                if (redogmSafer < 1) {
                                    groupMonitor.run(remoteHost, port);
                                } else { 
                                    …
                                }
                                redogmSafer = 100;
                            } catch ( Exception e ) { … }
                        }
                    };
```

Whether you catch `Throwable`, `Exception`, or some more specific exception(s) is up to you and your team to decide as appropriate to your situation.

This topic has been addressed multiple times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more. Specifically, see [*ScheduledExecutorService Exception handling*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6894595/642706).

Comment: so once the method groupMonitor.run() gets an exception it will get called again, right?

Comment: i need the runnable to call groupMonitor.run() each time the method returns because of an exception like connection lost ETC.

Comment: @aqwertyyyz Your `Runnable` object’s `run` method will run every so often, after elapsing the amount of time you specify in your call to `scheduleAtFixedRate`. If you pass 500 milliseconds, then every half-second the `Runnable` object’s `run` method executes. In your case, if your `if` test passes, `groupMonitor.run` executes. What that method does, I cannot address as you do not explain `groupMonitor.run(remoteHost, port)`.  But I can say that if during one of the executions of that method an `Exception` is thrown and not caught, that will be the last execution of the runnable’s `run`.

Comment: i will update the answer to add more clarity to the3 methods work